# Accelerometer Correction - Allowing the player to play from any angle

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, accelerometer

I want the accelerometer to work such that the player can play with the phone at any angle. Ideally, my code would log the phone's position when they start the game, then they'd be able to play from whatever position they want from game to game without having to adjust settings by just starting in that position.

```
-(void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration    *)acceleration
{

    NSLog(@"x : %g", acceleration.x);
    NSLog(@"y : %g", acceleration.y);
    NSLog(@"z : %g", acceleration.z);

    delta.y = acceleration.y;
    delta.x = acceleration.x;

    Player.center = CGPointMake(Player.center.x + delta.y, Player.center.y + delta.x);

  }

}
```

I've searched many, many threads on this and found a lot of answers, but none that I could get to work for my program. One video suggested:

```
    delta.y = acceleration.y;
    delta.x = (acceleration.x)*cos(w) - acceleration.z*sin(w);
```

Which seems to be the right idea, but I don't know how to assign w.

Comment: Acceleration by itself should not register the position of the device. That's where rotation comes in. If acceleration registers any value, while rotating around the accelerator chip, then there's something wrong. Maybe the accelerations you see are already corrected for position before you get them? In that case you should look for uncorrected values.

Comment: Excuse me if I am misunderstanding your point, but this code does register movement of the device. If I place it flat, then the object is still. If it is tilted in any direction, then the object moves. What I'm wanting is for the device to register the "flat position" - where the object does not move - at the beginning of the game. So, if the player is holding the phone at a 45 degree angle when the game starts, that is the "flat position" and any movement from it will move the object.

Comment: The accelerometers only measure lateral movement. They don't know about degrees. If you're on your back with the phone above you and move it left-right, that's the same as if you're on your side and and move it left-right (with respect to you), even though it's now moving up/down. In more technical terms, the acceleration axis are fixed to the phone.

Comment: Ok, would you be able to point me to the type of code that I should be using?

Comment: I don't program iOS, so I can't help you there. I just wanted to point you to a theoretical inconsistency in your request.

Answer (score 0):

I don't program iOS, so I can't help you there. I just wanted to point you to a theoretical inconsistency in your request. If you want to correct movement according to the orientation of the phone, you first have to get the orientation (which you cannot get from accelerometers only).

You will need either something which measures eg. the magnetic field, o gyroscopes (i.e. rotational accelerometers). You then use the positional info to correct (matrix multiplication) the translational info.

Here's some math background:

http://electronic-engineering.ch/study/ins/ins.html#phys_math_bg

Don't worry too much about all the integrals. If you don't want ultimate precision, you can probably just sum instead and do an approximation.